# Restrict GRUB to primary display

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, grub, xrandr, multi-monitor

I am having an Asus motherboard with Intel chip-set which has dual display capability. I have installed Ubuntu in it. Problem is, when the system starts up, GRUB menu and splash are being displayed on both the displays. How to restrict the GRUB menu and splash to primary display.

Comment: This isn't a problem.  Your monitor setup gets handled later in the startup process.

Comment: BIOSes / UEFI firmwares treat multiple displays differently.  some will leave one monitor enabled and others disabled; others will clone the primary output to any other connected outputs.  GRUB follows the BIOS/firmware lead here; if it's configurable at all it'll be in the BIOS/firmware settings.